Ruby class constructor using `()` rather than `.new()`
Please do not ask me "why do you want to do this?"  I'm just exploring the nooks and crannies of Ruby, with no specific goals in mind.
Some Ruby classes can be instantiated with just parentheses rather than explicitly invoking the #new method.  For example,
irb> require 'pathname'
irb> p=Pathname('/etc/xdg/autostart')
  => #<Pathname:/etc/xdg/autostart>
irb> n=Pathname.new('/etc/xdg/autostart')
  => #<Pathname:/etc/xdg/autostart>
irb> p==n
  => true

And some use this for casting/coercion, as in Integer(4.5).  And there are probably other uses I haven't encountered yet, or can't remember.
However, I haven't found a way to do this for custom classes:
irb> class Foo ; def initialize(*args) ; @args=args ; end ; end
  => :initialize
irb> f1=Foo.new(1,2,3)
  => #<Foo:0x00007f330a29f4e8 @args=[1, 2, 3]>
irb> fp=Foo(1,2,3)
(irb):7:in `<main>': undefined method `Foo' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  for

The only thing I can figure out is that both Pathname and Integer (for example) use C code, and somehow wnd up being Kernel methods:
irb> Object.method(:Pathname)
  => #<Method: #<Class:Object>(Kernel)#Pathname(_)>
irb> Object.method(:Integer)
  => #<Method: #<Class:Object>(Kernel)#Integer(*)>
irb> Object.method(:Foo)
(irb):10:in `method': undefined method `Foo' for class `#<Class:Object>' (NameError)
Did you mean?  for

So this appears to be something provided by the C/.so extension code.
However, can it be done simply with native Ruby code without resorting to a kludge like the following?
irb> Object.define_method(:Foo) { |*args| Foo.new(*args) }
  => :Foo
irb> Foo(1,2,3)
  => #<Foo:0x00007f330a3b9018 @args=[1, 2, 3]>


I'm not nearly familiar enough with Ruby to answer, but "somehow wind up being Kernel methods" sounds like something that would be a natural consequence of "using C code" (i.e., being implemented inside the interpreter itself, in C), rather than something mystical. That is, I would guess that this is how Ruby indicates that the method is part of the interpreter's implementation.

Does this answer your question? How to create an object in Ruby without using new

@KarlKnechtel you're right in that these methods are implemented in C but they are typically in the Ruby core or stdlib and not technically a part of the interpreter itself. It's not because you can't do it in Ruby but rather for performance reasons.

Those global methods are so-called module functions defined in Kernel. You can define your own global function this way: (using the Ruby 3 shorthand syntax for defining methods)
module Kernel
  def Foo(...) = Foo.new(...)
  module_function :Foo
end

The above defines a method Kernel#Foo which forwards all arguments to Foo.new. Since Object includes Kernel, this allows to create a Foo instances from within objects via:
Foo(1, 2, 3) #=> #<Foo:0x000000010633e120 @args=[1, 2, 3]>

In addition, module_function makes the method available as a class method:
Kernel.Foo(1, 2, 3) #=> #<Foo:0x0000000108b00398 @args=[1, 2, 3]>

it also marks the instance method as being private so you can't call it with any other explicit receiver:
:hello.Foo(1, 2, 3)
# NoMethodError: private method `Foo' called for an instance of Symbol

This is also how Integer, Pathname etc. are integrated.
Note that the built-in global methods which correspond to a class are intended primarily for converting values to that class, e.g. Integer("123") #=> 123. They don't just pass along the arguments. (Integer doesn't even respond to new)

Adding to this: The Pathname() Kernel method is defined here in C. There's nothing to stop you from defining a method in ruby, of course.

@TomLord - the same is true for almost all the special constuctors in the Ruby core; Integer, Float, Rational, String, Array, Hash, etc.

Thank you for that detailed explanation!  So, there's no mechanism for this short of metaprogramming it into Kernel, eh?  Good to know; thanks!

@RoUS you essentially want a global function Foo() but in Ruby there are no functions, only methods. Therefore you have to define it as a method in a module which is available from everywhere. In Ruby, that "global" module is Kernel. It's not really metaprogramming, it's just where global methods are defined. From the docs: "The Kernel module is included by class Object, so its methods are available in every Ruby object [...] and thus can be called in functional form."

@RoUS Meta-programming is "code that writes code". For example, define_method or instance_variable_set. There's nothing "meta" about adding a method to the Kernel module; it's just regular programming.
